# Connect to k8s created with conjure_up from external kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, juju

I have installed a k8s cluster using conjure up on ubuntu 16.04 server. I can connect to the cluster from the ubuntu server but when I try and connect from my local machine it doesn't work (after copying the config file), all the ip addresses in the config are 10.x.x.x which are internal to the server.

How do I/Can I configure conjure Up/juju/kubernetes to expose something on the external ip address of the machine?

Ideally i would like to be able to connect to the cluster using kubectl from an external device.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work", what do you mean? Are there any errors? What have you tried?

Comment: It just fails because the config file I copied has 10.x ip addresses but the server is on a 192 network. I have gave up with this setup because even when i accepted I couldn't use kubectl from outside the machine i still couldn't get the cluster to respond to external traffic. I tried using proxy pass on nginx which sent it to the right place but then I just got empty responses i.e. no headers or content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the kubectl proxy?

kubectl proxy --port=443 --address=0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts=10.x.x.x